# listagg produces ORA-01489 if used as window function in conditional expression

Tags: sql, oracle, case, listagg, analytic-functions

My query returns many (thousands of) rows.
Column `l` has certain value for very small amount of rows (up to 10).
For each such row I want to output aggregated comma-separated values of very short (up to 5 chars) varchar column `v` over all of these rows.
For rows not having the special value of `l` I want to simply output the `v` value for that row.

Synthetized example of same problem: from first 10000 integers, I want to output `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9` for each single-digit number; that number for multiple-digit number. (Yes, silly example but real case makes sense.)

```sql
with x (v,l) as (
  select to_char(level), length(to_char(level)) from dual connect by level <= 10000
)
select case l
         when 1 then listagg(v,',') within group (order by v) over (partition by l)
         else v
       end
from x
order by 1;
```

The problem is, `listagg` function fails on `ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long` error.

I am aware of 4000 char limit of `listagg` function as well as xmlagg-based workaround. I just don't get the limit is enough for data I want to concatenate even though not enough for all data. In example above, the partition of 9 single-digit numbers fits into 4000 chars, the partition of 9000 four-digit numbers not. I expected the `case` expression would prevent execution of window for unrelated rows but, for some reason, it seems the db engine evaluates window for all rows. (Also note that `order by` clause causes query to fail-fast - without it some rows are returned before failure.)

Can you please explain some reasoning for this behaviour? I suspect the window computation is logically before `select` clause but without any evidence. Reproduced on Oracle 11g, [18c](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bbf228da69d20a095c924e8870dcd946) and 19 (livesql).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are using `SQL` which is not procedural, so you **can't expect** that some parts of the code path will not be executed, only because they are not used. (So filling a bug as other suggested will have no success).

Anyway you can do the often used trick based on the fact that `listagg` ignores `null` values.

So this formulation works fine:

```
with x (v,l) as (
  select to_char(level), length(to_char(level)) from dual connect by level <= 10000
)
select   nvl(listagg(case when l = 1 then v end,',') within group (order by v) over (partition by l),v) lst
from x
order by 1;
```

giving

```
LST
------------------
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
..
10
100
1000
10000
```

The explanation of the problem can be found in the execution plan (showing only the relevant part)

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                       | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                |      |     1 |    35 |     4  (50)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY                  |      |     1 |    35 |     4  (50)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   WINDOW SORT                   |      |     1 |    35 |     4  (50)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    VIEW                         |      |     1 |    35 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |     CONNECT BY WITHOUT FILTERING|      |       |       |            |          |
|   5 |      FAST DUAL                  |      |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
Column Projection Information (identified by operation id):
-----------------------------------------------------------
 
   1 - (#keys=1) CASE "L" WHEN 1 THEN LISTAGG("V",',') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY 
       "V") OVER ( PARTITION BY "L") ELSE "V" END [4000]
   2 - (#keys=2) "L"[NUMBER,22], "V"[VARCHAR2,40], LISTAGG("V",',') WITHIN 
       GROUP ( ORDER BY "V") OVER ( PARTITION BY "L")[4000]
   3 - "V"[VARCHAR2,40], "L"[NUMBER,22]
   4 - LEVEL[4]
```

So in the line 2  the `listagg` is calculated (for all rows) only to be filtered in the line 1.

Comment: thanks, yes, I obviously can't, I hoped optimizer would be smart enough to recognize it does not have to compute large partitions. Your query returns null for v=10, l=2, I need to return 10 (similarly for all subsequent rows).

Comment: Very sorry @TomášZáluský I updated the query with the `NVL` to consider the `else` part.

Comment: Works perfectly. Very smart trick. (Actually rewriting nvl expression into real code took 5 lines of SQL code because of removing duplicates, so it took some additional effort but story has happy end.) I also very appreciate your reasoning in explain plan. Upvote, accept and kudos in general :-)

Answer (score 1):

It is odd that you do get an error about the 4000 character limit even though no result is longer than 4000 characters. Maybe you could file this as a bug to Oracle Support.

Another workaround is to make use of the `ON OVERFLOW` logic of the `LISTAGG` function if you are on Oracle 12.2 or higher. Using `LISTAGG (v, ',' ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE)` in the query allows the query to be run without error and does not truncate any values (at least in the example).

Comment: I am going to ask on AskTom at first but unfortunately, asking question is disabled at the moment. Yes, the `on overflow` clause would be solution if my main db wasn't 11g... Anyway, thanks :-)