# Oracle SQL - LISTAGG will be called even condition of CASE statement will not be fullfilled

Tags: sql, oracle, case, distinct, listagg

I have to work on an oracle DB server with the version `Oracle Database 12c Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production`. Therefore I cannot use `ON OVERFLOW ...` when using the LISTAGG function. To overcome an aggregation of a column which has a size bigger than 4000 bytes I wanted to use the suggested solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22624072/11986067), such that I will not get the error `01489. 00000 -  "result of string concatenation is too long"`.

Unfortunately this approach does not work for me. Even with a condition of 1=1 which should never call the LISTAGG function I got the mentioned error.

Here the query:

```sql
select distinct t.id,
    (case when 1=1 then
        'Test'
    else
        LISTAGG(mh.RNAME1, '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY mh.RNAME1)
    end) as RNAME1LIST,
    (case when 1=1 then
        'Test'
    else
        LISTAGG(mh.RNAME2, '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY mh.RNAME2)
    end) as RNAME2LIST, 
    t.email1 as EMAIL1
from mh 
join mp on MH.MID = MP.MID
RIGHT JOIN T ON mh.T_ID = T.ID
group by t.id, t.email1;
```

I am looking for an explanation of this behavior and an alternative approach such that I will not get the mentioned error.

Comment: Maybe Oracle is doing some pre-compilation and then fails your code based on that.

Comment: For your statement `case` is evaluated after the aggregation (as it encloses aggregate function), but the aggregation itself is done during the `group by`. So Oracle have no possibility to avoid it

Comment: [Related discussion](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4097998/oracle-bug-aggregates-in-case-expressions-negate-short-circuit-evaluation)

Comment: An [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66128339/4808122) related question and proposed workaround ...

Comment: No need to do SELECT DISTINCT here, your GROUP BY returns no duplicates.

Comment: `case` _expression_.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, now I am aware why my query with the case expression does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CLOB

```sql
drop function listagg_clob;
drop type listagg_clob_t;

create or replace package list_const_p
is
  list_sep varchar2(10) := ',';
end list_const_p;
/
sho err

create type listagg_clob_t as object(
  v_liststring varchar2(32767),
  v_clob       clob,
  v_templob    number,

  static function ODCIAggregateInitialize(
    sctx IN OUT listagg_clob_t
  ) return number,
  member function ODCIAggregateIterate(
    self IN OUT listagg_clob_t, value IN varchar2
  ) return number,
  member function ODCIAggregateTerminate(
    self IN OUT listagg_clob_t, returnValue OUT clob, flags IN number
  ) return number,
  member function ODCIAggregateMerge(
    self IN OUT listagg_clob_t, ctx2 IN OUT listagg_clob_t
  ) return number
);
/
sho err

create or replace type body listagg_clob_t is

static function ODCIAggregateInitialize(sctx IN OUT listagg_clob_t)
return number is
begin
  sctx := listagg_clob_t('', '', 0);
  return ODCIConst.Success;
end;

member function ODCIAggregateIterate(
  self IN OUT listagg_clob_t,
  value IN varchar2
) return number is
begin
  if nvl(lengthb(v_liststring),0) + nvl(lengthb(value),0) <= 4000 then
    self.v_liststring:=self.v_liststring || value || list_const_p.list_sep;
  else
    if self.v_templob = 0 then
      dbms_lob.createtemporary(self.v_clob, true, dbms_lob.call);
      self.v_templob := 1;
    end if;
    dbms_lob.writeappend(self.v_clob, length(self.v_liststring), v_liststring);
    self.v_liststring := value || list_const_p.list_sep;
  end if;
  return ODCIConst.Success;
end;

member function ODCIAggregateTerminate(
  self IN OUT listagg_clob_t,
  returnValue OUT clob,
  flags IN number
) return number is
begin
  if self.v_templob != 0 then
    dbms_lob.writeappend(self.v_clob, length(self.v_liststring), self.v_liststring);
    dbms_lob.trim(self.v_clob, dbms_lob.getlength(self.v_clob) - 1);
  else
    self.v_clob := substr(self.v_liststring, 1, length(self.v_liststring) - 1);
  end if;
  returnValue := self.v_clob;
  return ODCIConst.Success;
end;

member function ODCIAggregateMerge(self IN OUT listagg_clob_t, ctx2 IN OUT listagg_clob_t) return number is
begin
  if ctx2.v_templob != 0 then
    if self.v_templob != 0 then
      dbms_lob.append(self.v_clob, ctx2.v_clob);
      dbms_lob.freetemporary(ctx2.v_clob);
      ctx2.v_templob := 0;
    else
      self.v_clob := ctx2.v_clob;
      self.v_templob := 1;
      ctx2.v_clob := '';
      ctx2.v_templob := 0;
    end if;
  end if;
  if nvl(lengthb(self.v_liststring),0) + nvl(lengthb(ctx2.v_liststring),0) <= 4000 then
    self.v_liststring := self.v_liststring || ctx2.v_liststring;
    ctx2.v_liststring := '';
  else
    if self.v_templob = 0 then
      dbms_lob.createtemporary(self.v_clob, true, dbms_lob.call);
      self.v_templob := 1;
    end if;
    dbms_lob.writeappend(self.v_clob, length(self.v_liststring), self.v_liststring);
    dbms_lob.writeappend(self.v_clob, length(ctx2.v_liststring), ctx2.v_liststring);
    self.v_liststring := '';
    ctx2.v_liststring := '';
  end if;
  return ODCIConst.Success;
end;
end;
/
sho err

CREATE or replace FUNCTION listagg_clob (input varchar2) RETURN clob
PARALLEL_ENABLE AGGREGATE USING listagg_clob_t;
/
sho err;
;
```

test sql

```sql
SELECT listagg_clob(n)
  FROM (SELECT LEVEL * 100 n FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL<=10000);
```

http://www.itpub.net/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=2094642&extra=&highlight=concat&page=1

Comment: You can use clob to break the 4000 byte limit

Answer (score 1):

This is because aggregation actually happens on-the-fly, when Oracle evaluates groups of rows, but `case` expression is in `select` list so evaluated on the result dataset.

Processing that you expect should buffer all the input and maintain cross-references (aggregated to source rows). Or deal with complex dependency tree, because in `select` list you may use aggregated result alongside the `group by` column(s) in the same expression, which may also introduce a cyclic dependency.

Below is the example of some logging function to see, that it is evaluated at the aggregation step regardless of the `case` result. And the `case` is evaluated after the aggregation.

> ```
> /*Logging table*/
> create table t (
>   /*To have a sequence*/
>   id number GENERATED ALWAYS as IDENTITY(START with 1 INCREMENT by 1)
>   , val number
>   , src varchar2(100)
> )
> ```

> ```
> /*Logger to check what is going on here*/
> create function f_test(
>   p_val in number
>   , p_src in varchar2
> ) return varchar2
> as
>   pragma autonomous_transaction;
> begin
>   insert into t(val, src)
>   values (p_val, p_src);
>   commit;
>   
>   return p_val;
> end;
> /
> ```

> ```
> /*Log aggregation function invocation and case/where evaluation*/
> with a as (
>   select
>     level as l
>     , mod(level, 3) as grp
>   from dual
>   connect by level < 7
> )
> select
>   grp
>   , case
>       when f_test(grp, 'CASE CONDITION') > 0
>       then f_test(grp, 'CASE RESULT')
>       else max(f_test(grp, 'AGG'))
>     end as res_agg
> from a
> where f_test(grp, 'WHERE') = grp
> group by grp
> ```
>
> ```
> GRP | RES_AGG
> --: | :------
>   2 | 2      
>   0 | 0      
>   1 | 1
> ```

> ```
> select *
> from t
> order by id
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | VAL | SRC           
> -: | --: | :-------------
>  1 |   1 | WHERE         
>  2 |   1 | AGG           
>  3 |   2 | WHERE         
>  4 |   2 | AGG           
>  5 |   0 | WHERE         
>  6 |   0 | AGG           
>  7 |   1 | WHERE         
>  8 |   1 | AGG           
>  9 |   2 | WHERE         
> 10 |   2 | AGG           
> 11 |   0 | WHERE         
> 12 |   0 | AGG           
> 13 |   2 | CASE CONDITION
> 14 |   2 | CASE RESULT   
> 15 |   0 | CASE CONDITION
> 16 |   1 | CASE CONDITION
> 17 |   1 | CASE RESULT
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f46125889b57c8033fa9e8094ed90c21)*

However, you may workaround this as in Oracle 12c+ you may declare local functions in `with` clause. This way you can aggregate your data as a collection type and then concatenate it in PL/SQL. Or as a general and faster approach: define your custom listagg for `clob` datatype as described in another answer.

> ```
> with function f_listagg_clob(
>   p_vc2_tab in sys.odcivarchar2list
>   , p_sep in varchar2 default ', '
> )
>   return clob
> as
>   r_clob clob;
> begin
>   for i in 1..p_vc2_tab.count loop
>     r_clob := r_clob || case when i > 1 then p_sep end || p_vc2_tab(i);
>   end loop;
>
>   return r_clob;
> end;
>
> a as (
>   select
>     dbms_random.string('X', 100) as str
>   from dual
>   connect by level < 1000
> )
> select length(f_listagg_clob(cast(collect(str) as sys.odcivarchar2list))) as result_len
> from a
> ```
>
> ```
> | RESULT_LEN |
> | ---------: |
> |     101896 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6997b0fb68778d9ae7e0267861a713ef)*